# Group toghether Node properties and return as a view in Cypher

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am working with v2.2.3 of Neo4J and Spring Neo4j Data SDN 4
I want to return a few properties of a node using a cypher query and map them into attributes of a POJO.My function in Spring data repository looks something like this

```
@Query(
"MATCH(n:ServiceProvider{profileStatus:{pStatus},currentResidenceState:{location}}) RETURN n.name,n.currentResidenceAddress ,n.employmentStatus,"
                       + "n.idProofType,n.idProofNumber 
ORDER BY n.registrationDate DESC SKIP{skip} LIMIT {limit}")
List<AdminSearchMapResult> getServiceProviderRecords(
       @Param("pStatus")String pStatus,
       @Param("location")String location,
       @Param("skip") int skip,@Param("limit")int limit);
```

I get an error like

```
Scalar response queries must only return one column. Make sure your cypher query only returns one item.
```

I think its because of the fact that I cant bundle all the returned attributes into a view that can map into the POJO

If I return the node itself and map it into a POJO it works

Kindly guide

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `@QueryResult`

Annotate the `AdminSearchMapResult` POJO with `@QueryResult`. For example:

```
@QueryResult
public class AdminSearchMapResult {

  String name;
  String currentResidenceAddress;
...

}
```

Optionally annotate properties with `@Property(name = "n.idProofType")` if the alias is different from the field name.

Comment: Thanks will revert with the results

Comment: @QueryResult annotation could not be imported

Comment: I am using the following dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: org.neo4j - neo4j-ogm- 1.1.0   
org.springframework.data- spring-data-neo4j - 4.0.0.M1
org.neo4j.app - neo4j-server - 2.2.3
org.springframework.data - spring-data-commons - 1.10.0.RELEASE   <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
   <name>Spring</name>
   <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
  </repository>

  <repository>
   <id>neo4j</id>
   <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>

Comment: Please use RC1 instead of M1. You need only use
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I have used the RC1 version now .But the problem is that in my Neo4JConfiguration file I get error java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories.repositoryBaseClass() at the time of server startup.The code contains annotations  Configuration
EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.app.repository")
EnableTransactionManagement

Comment: I am referring to the following doc http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/4.0.x/reference/pdf/spring-data-neo4j-reference.pdf

Comment: Do you have any dependencies on spring data commons? Please share your dependencies

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0.RC1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency><dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
   <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>

Comment: Please try spring-data-commons 1.11.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT 
Include  <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>